# Need assistance connecting VST Sequencer in Ableton to External Synth

Tags: ableton-live, sequencer

I have Sequence Air on first midi track and Minilogue XD set as an External Instrument on the second midi track. I can get sound from the minilogue but I cant figure out how to get the sequencer to run through the XD. They are both on midi channel 1 and I have the "input" of the External Instrument as the sequencer https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0y0G.jpg
I have the External Instrument set to Minilogue XD SOUND https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7nYv.jpg On the external instrument I see an option for "audio from" but those are only external inputs.

Let me know if you need any additional info.